# Como fazer com que um ponteiro aponte para NULL?

Tags: c, array, lista, matriz, lista-encadeada

Preciso que uma posição de um elemento em um vetor dinâmico seja vazia, para que eu possa verificar se posso colocar um elemento dentro dela posteriormente. Porém, o compilador não permite. Segue meu código:

```
MATRIZ_ESPARSA *criar_matriz(MATRIZ_ESPARSA *matriz, int nr_linhas, int nr_colunas){
    matriz = (MATRIZ_ESPARSA *)malloc(sizeof(MATRIZ_ESPARSA));
    (*matriz).linhas = (CELULA *)malloc(nr_linhas*sizeof(CELULA));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr_linhas; i++){
        (*matriz).linhas[i] = NULL;
    }
    (*matriz).colunas = (CELULA *)malloc(nr_colunas*sizeof(CELULA));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr_colunas; i++){
        (*matriz).colunas[i] = NULL;
    }
    return(matriz); 
}
```

Verificação se existe algum elemento:

```
if((*matriz).linhas[linha] == NULL && (*matriz).colunas[coluna] == NULL){
    (*matriz).linhas[linha] = *novo;
    (*matriz).linhas[linha].direita = NULL;
    (*matriz).colunas[coluna] = *novo;
    (*matriz).colunas[coluna].abaixo = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: In function ‘criar_matriz’:
pdf4.c:98:29: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘CELULA {aka struct CELULA}’ from type ‘void *’
         (*matriz).linhas[i] = NULL;

Comment: `MATRIZ_ESPARSA.linhas` é do tipo `CELULA**`?

Comment: nao, é do tipo CELULA *

Comment: Você está confundindo a tipagem. `(CELULA*)[i]` não é um ponteiro, mas sim `CELULA`. Como não é um ponteiro, não pode receber `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode incluir um flag indicador de `NULL` em cada uma das celulas da sua matriz, por exemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct CELULA {
    int is_null;
    double valor;
} CELULA;


typedef struct MATRIZ_ESPARSA {
    int nlinhas;
    int ncolunas;
    CELULA ** celulas;
} MATRIZ_ESPARSA;


MATRIZ_ESPARSA * matriz_criar( int ncolunas, int nlinhas )
{
    int y, x;

    /* Aloca a matriz */
    MATRIZ_ESPARSA * m = (MATRIZ_ESPARSA*) malloc( sizeof(MATRIZ_ESPARSA) );

    /* Aloca uma array de ponteiros */
    m->celulas = (CELULA**) malloc( nlinhas * sizeof(CELULA*) );

    /* Aloca uma array de doubles para cada linha da matriz */
    for( y = 0; y < nlinhas; y++ )
        m->celulas[y] = (CELULA*) calloc( ncolunas,  sizeof(CELULA) );

    /* Todas as celulas sao inicializadas com flag NULL */
    for( y = 0; y < nlinhas; y++ )
        for( x = 0; x < ncolunas; x++ )
            m->celulas[y][x].is_null = 1;

    m->nlinhas = nlinhas;
    m->ncolunas = ncolunas;

    return m;
}
```